# how to sync in multi-thread of Linux

Tags: linux

I have four threads, and i need to translate the data among these threads, the function like follow:

```
 theadFunc(){
    processing;
    __sync();
    processing; 
   }
```

Is there any sync functions in linux that make sure the threads will arrive at the same point. 
In windows , I use atomic add and atomic compare to implement the __sync(), and i didn't find the atomic compare function in Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use GCC's [Atomic builtins](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.1/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html#Atomic-Builtins) to do a compare and swap, but you may want to consider using a pthreads barrier instead. See the documentation for [`pthread_barrier_init`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_barrier_destroy.html) and [`pthread_barrier_wait`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_barrier_wait.html) for more information. You can also read this [pthreads primer](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~travitch/pthreads_primer.html) for a working example of barrier usage.